# Inferring Similarity in OWL Ontologies Based on Multiple Relationship Patterns

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, semantic-web, protege

I am working on a business ontology in Protegé and have encountered a challenge related to inferring relationships based on multiple relationship patterns. I am aware that this issue may arise due to the Open World Assumption, and I am seeking guidance on how to address it.

Consider the following:

1. We have two classes, `Class_A` and `Class_B`, both of which have instances/individuals `A_1...A_n` and `B_1...B_m`.
2. We have an object property `relationshipAB` with a domain of `Class_A` and a range of `Class_B`.
3. We also have an object property `similarA` with a domain and range of `Class_A`.

My goal is to create an axiom or rule that allows the reasoner to infer `similarA` relationships between individuals of `Class_A` based on assertions involving `relationshipAB`. More specifically, if two individuals `A_x` and `A_y` in `Class_A` have the exact same valued `B_i ... B_j` `relationshipAB` assertions, then a `similarA` relationship should be inferred between `A_x` and `A_y`.

In essence, this is like inferring a relationship based on other relationships having the exact same values/edges with another class (e.g., full-siblings with the same parents, but with an arbitrary number of "parents"). It can also be seen as the existence of multiple property chains based on all possible initial `A_ -> B_` legs.

I have tried do to this with SWRL rules, but SWRL is incapable of iterating over all relationships and comparing that to an other set.

Given the limitations of the Open World Assumption, what alternative approaches can be used to accomplish this task? Is it possible to "close" this part of the ontology to allow for the desired reasoning? Or is the only feasible approach to directly calculate and assert these similarity-type object properties using a query language like SPARQL?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since this deals very specifically with individuals, your best bet is likely to use SPARQL.

Comment: I would add an inverse property 'relationshipBA' for 'relationshipAB' and use a property chain 'relationshipAB o relationshipBA -> similarA'. but there is of course a side effect such as for every object  А_i that has a property relationshipAB be matched with a triple 'А_i, similarA, А_i'. but you will get the needed connections 'А_i, similarA, А_j ' for different А_i and А_j which has connections with same B_k

Comment: @iroli, I see, but then it does not take into account that all of those property chains need to be present between A_i and A_j. In your example similarA will exist if there is even just only one similar relationshipAB property to a specific B individual.